# individual PACK for a fleet of NFC

Tags: nfc

I read through the documentation of the **NXP NTAG I2c plus** and the documentation suggests that i should use a unique PACK for every NFC. Every NFC has a unique password, that I am setting up, but now i am asking myself: why do i need to create a unique individual PACK for every NFC. What are benefits in doing so and what downsides are there, if I decide to use the same PACK for the whole fleet.

i looked through the documentation and forums, but I could not find an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My understanding is that checking the PACK response increases the level of security a bit.

In the scenario where you program is sending the authentication command with your password to an custom piece of NFC hardware running custom software that is trying to pretend to be an authentic Tag. The custom hardware could just accept any password but if it did not send back the right PACK then your program would know that something is a miss and your program should raise an error.

Having unique PACK for each tag increases the security difficulty level a bit more over just using the same PACK for all Tags. Your program can match the PASSWORD to the correct PACK. Thus hackers who might have used various techniques like "Man in the middle" or RF eavesdropping to get a PACK from another Tag won't be able to use that PACK they have learned with other TAGs.

So the reason to use unique PACKS is the same reason to use unique PASSWORDS. The downside is a bit more complexity in your program, but if you have already worked out a way to keep the passwords secure then adding an extra bit of data for the matching PACK should not be too difficult.

Also remember the "Reader" hardware and software could be brute forced to give out passwords as this might be statically located somewhere. Getting a PACK of a TAG is harder.